# How to provide and save data for custom field in gallery.phtm on product edit page

Tags: admin, javascript, gallery

I have create custom field in admin product edit page image gallery popup in custom module with observer event. Now i want to provide data to this field from table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value and save it with observer catalog_product_save_after. How can I do this?
[image]

There is my observer

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout">
    <observer name="change_template" disabled="true"/>
    <observer name="custom_change_template" 
              instance="Module\Vendor\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver" />
</event>
</config>
```

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeTemplateObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::helper/gallery.phtml');
    }
}
```

There is part of template:

```
             <div class="admin__field field-image-custom-label">
                    <label class="admin__field-label" for="image-custom-label">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Label')) ?></span>
                    </label>

                    <div class="admin__field-control">
                            <input    data-role="image-description"
                                      id="custom_label"
                                      class="admin__control-input">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result i have create after plugin which add my new column to data object on front.

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery">
        <plugin name="afterCreateBatchBaseSelect" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\Gallery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

```
public function afterCreateBatchBaseSelect(
        ProductGallery $subject,
        Select $select
    ) {
        $select->columns('custom_label');

        return $select;
    }
```

So my input will be like this

```
<div class="admin__field field-custom-label">
   <label class="admin__field-label" for="image-custom-label">
      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Label')) ?></span>
   </label>
      <div class="admin__field-control">
         <input
            data-role="custom-label"
            id="custom_label_field"
            name="custom_label"
            class="admin__control-textarea"
            value="<%- data.custom_label %>">
      </div>
</div>

<input  type="hidden" name="hidden_custom_label">
```

Then i have rewrite productGallery with requirejs-config and add

```
$dialog.on('change', '[data-role="custom-label"]', function (e) {
                var target = $(e.target),
                    targetName = 'custom_label',
                    desc = target.val(),
                    imageData = $dialog.data('imageData');

                this.element.find('input[type="hidden"][name="hidden_custom_label"]').val(desc);

                imageData.custom_label = desc;
                imageData['custom_label'] = desc;

                this.element.trigger('updateImageTitle', {
                    imageData: imageData
                });
            }.bind(this));
```

And in the end in this file product-gallery.js i've save value on close popup with ajax